# Sigmoid Function in Numpy

Tags: numpy, sigmoid

For fast computations, I have to implement my sigmoid function in Numpy this is the code below

```
   def sigmoid(Z):
    """
    Implements the sigmoid activation in bumpy

    Arguments:
    Z -- numpy array of any shape

    Returns:
    A -- output of sigmoid(z), same shape as Z
    cache -- returns Z, useful during backpropagation
    """

    cache=Z

    print(type(Z))
    print(Z)
    A=1/(1+(np.exp((-Z))))

    return A, cache
```

Also some relevant information:

```
  Z=(np.matmul(W,A)+b)
```

and the type of Z is:

```
  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Sadly I am getting a: "bad operand type for unary -: 'tuple' "
I have tried to work around this problem without any luck.I appreciate any suggestions.
Best

Comment: `Z` is here apparently a tuple, not a numpy array, or some other array-like object.

Comment: Can you supply more code to indicate what is being inputted into the function?

Answer (score 12):

**This worked for me.** I think no need to use cache because you already initialized it. Try this code below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 

z = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100) 
def sigmoid(z):
    return 1/(1 + np.exp(-z))

a = sigmoid(z)
plt.plot(z, a) 
plt.xlabel("z") 
plt.ylabel("sigmoid(z)")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing this error most likely because your `Z`, while it is of type `numpy.ndarray`, contains a tuple.  For instance, consider this definition of `Z`.

```
Z = np.array([1, (1, 2, 3), 3])
```

If you run your `sigmoid` function on this `Z`, it will print that `Z` is a `numpy.ndarray` but produce the `TypeError` you get because numpy broadcasts the unary negation across the members of `Z`, one of which is a tuple, and tuple does not implement unary negation.

Answer (score 0):

While implementing sigmoid function is quite easy, sometimes the argument passed in the function might cause errors.

Code snippet

```
def sigmoid_function(z):
""" this function implements the sigmoid function, and 
expects a numpy array as argument """
    
    if isinstance(z, numpy.ndarray):
        continue
    
    sigmoid = 1.0/(1.0 + np.exp(-z))
    return sigmoid
```

Few important points to keep in mind:-

using 1.0 in value of sigmoid will result in a float type output

checking the type of argument before performing your computations over
them is a good programming practice. It can help avoid confusions later

```
Why is sigmoid function used so often?
```

Sigmoid function is used for squishing the range of values into a range  (0, 1). There are multiple other function which can do that, but a very important point boosting its popularity is how simply it can express its derivatives, which comes handy in backpropagation

Implementating derivative of sigmoid

```
def sigmoid_derivative(z):
    """ this function implements the derivative of a sigmoid function """
    
    return sigmoid_function(z) * (1.0 - sigmoid_function(z))
```

derivative of sigmoid can be expressed in terms of sigmoid!!