# What do we use instead of the deprecated GradientBoostingClassifier._loss?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Attribute [`GradientBoostingClassifier._loss`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html) has been [deprecated](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/23079).

What do we use instead, [e.g.](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/15139):

```py
GBC = GradientBoostingClassifier(...)
GBC.fit(X, y)
for y_pred in GBC.staged_decision_function(X_test):
    print(GBC.loss_(y_test, y_pred))
```

**NB**. The `loss` argument to `GradientBoostingClassifier` defaults to `log_loss`, but [`sklearn.metrics.log_loss`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.log_loss.html) and  `GBC.loss_` return dramatically different values (the former mostly useless). In fact, `loss_` is [`_gb_losses.BinomialDeviance`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/ensemble/_gb_losses.py#L633) - an internal class.

Answer (score 0):

When `loss` is the default (`log_loss`), one can recover deviance like this:

```py
def sigmoid(z):
    "Convert log odds to probabilities."
    # https://stackoverflow.com/q/60746851/850781
    return 1/(1 + np.exp(-z))

GBC = GradientBoostingClassifier(...)
GBC.fit(X, y)
for y_pred in GBC.staged_decision_function(X_test):
    assert math.isclose(GBC.loss_(y_test, y_pred) / 2,
                        sklearn.metrics.log_loss(y_test, sigmoid(y_pred)))
```

However, the arbitrary `loss` case is still missing.